# How do I tell iTunes to display the Downloads "playlist" with AppleScript (on Mac OS X)?

Tags: macos, applescript, itunes, playlist

I select certain playlists in iTunes so frequently that I've created AppleScripts to display them, and then bound them to keyboard shortcuts with [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/).

Here's an AppleScript for displaying my "New Podcasts" playlist:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set view of (browser window 1) to user playlist "New Podcasts"
end tell
```

And here's an AppleScript for displaying "Music":

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set view of (browser window 1) to user playlist 1
end tell
```

I'd like to be able to go to "Downloads" (while new podcasts are downloading), but I can't figure out how to do it from an AppleScript.  I've tried `set view of (browser window 1) to user playlist 1` with various numbers instead of 1, and `set view of (browser window 1) to user playlist "Downloads"`, but none of these work.  I don't see any sign of Downloads in the iTunes AppleScript Dictionary.

Is it possible to set the view to "Downloads" from AppleScript?  How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTunes"
    tell outline 1 of scroll area 2 of window "iTunes"
        set statictexts to value of static text of rows
        repeat with i from 1 to number of statictexts
            if ((item i of statictexts) as text) starts with "Downloads" then
                set value of attribute "AXSelected" of row i to true
                return
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way of doing this. The Downloads "playlist" is not recognized as an object.

As you can see I've tried accessing the download "playlist" using two methods and both give me the same error.
[image]
[image]

It should also be noted that you will get the same error if you try to select any of the following "playlists" : Apps, iTunes Store, Ringtones, Ping.

Check out this post for an alternative solution : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837135/how-do-i-tell-itunes-to-display-the-downloads-playlist-with-applescript-on-ma/7839791#7839791)